# How to set nginx variable to Lua table/array

Tags: nginx, lua

How can one return a table/array from a `set_by_lua_*` directive so that it can later be read by another `set_by_lua_*` directive?

My intent is returning a complex value once and then put pieces of the returned value in other variables. In an ideal world this is what I would write (non-working example):

```
location {
    set_by_lua_file $info '/my/library/do_stuff_with_headers_and_env.lua';

    set_by_lua $language 'return $info["language"]';
    set_by_lua $best_server 'return $info["server"]';
    set_by_lua $last_user 'return $info["user"]';

    echo "Best server for $language is $best_server (last used by $last_user)";
}
```

One could simply set these variables inside the script using `ngx.var`, but I would like to write the script file as a sort of library, and let the user extract only the pieces of information they need.

Given that `set_by_lua_*` does not support tables/arrays (`set_by_lua $x 'return {"foo", "bar"}';` sets `$x` to `nil`), **are there best practices, workarounds or idiomatic ways to return a table/array from `set_by_lua_*` directives?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

**Define variables first and set value in script**

```
location / {
    set_by_lua $language '';
    set_by_lua $best_server '';
    set_by_lua $last_user '';

    set_by_lua_file $info '/my/library/do_stuff_with_headers_and_env.lua';


    echo "Best server for $language is $best_server (last used by $last_user)";
}
```

In your `do_stuff_with_headers_and_env.lua` you will have below

```
local info = {language ="english"}
ngx.var.language = info["language"]
```

**Define variables in encoded form**

```
location / {
    set_by_lua $info '
         local cjson=require("cjson")
         return cjson.encode({language="english"})
       ';

    set_by_lua $language '
         local cjson=require("cjson")
         return cjson.decode(ngx.var.info)["language"];
       ';

    echo "Best server for $language";
 }
```